# sshd_config GatewayPorts

Tags: linux, security, ssh

Is there any reason why I should not set `GatewayPorts yes` in my sshd_config file if the hosts are only going to be internal to the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonably safe to do so; the only caveat is if there's any way for that machine to be compromised it's a bit less insecure than not.  If it's a purely internal machine with no external ports forwarded to it or anything, it should be just fine.